# TASM how to get command line arguments?

Tags: assembly, tasm

how do you get command line argument in TASM?
Pretty simple in MASM32

`invoke GetCL,1,addr buffer`

Comment: What OS are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you should always be able to use the OS's API functions. For Windows programs, start with [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx).